# How to remove UIViewController from container view?

Tags: ios, swift

This is what I have done. The adding part is working, but the remove part is not:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ child: UIViewController, containerView: UIView) {
        addChildViewController(child)
        containerView.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    func remove(containerView: UIView) {
        guard parent != nil else { return }

        willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        removeFromParentViewController()
        containerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

I tried to update this code which originally would add and remove child view controllers. But what I want is to add and remove from a container view.

Can someone point out what is the problem with the remove part ?

Comment: Both `add` and `remove` should each have one parameter - the view controller that is being added or removed.

Comment: Ok, but then how do I tell it to remove it from container view ? Not self.view ?

Comment: What is your intent? Is `remove` to be called on the containing (parent) view controller or the contained (child) view controller?

Comment: I think the contained one. I want the added vc to be removed from container view.

Comment: If `remove` is called on the child, then `add` should be called on the child and the only parameter to `add` should be the parent view controller.

Comment: But I tried that, and my view controller is added to the parent view controller. My container view is half in size....so the added view controller should be added to the container view (half of the screen) not parent view controller which is all of the screen. Not sure if I make myself clear.

Comment: you need to set the frame then

Comment: Before this line **containerView.addSubview(child.view)** do **child.view.frame = containerView.frame**

Comment: @Sh_Khan: If I do containerView.addSubview, its working. I don't need to set the frame. But I can't remove it.

Comment: remove it from the child ,,, do **child.remove()** ,  this will avoid headache of knowing wether the parent vc's view is self.view or container

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `add` and `remove` should both be from the same point of view. Either `self` should be the parent view controller in both cases or `self` should be the child view controller in both cases. Right now, you seem to have `add` with `self` as the parent and `remove` with `self` as the child.

Here's your extension where `self` is the child in both:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ parent: UIViewController) {
        parent.addChildViewController(self)
        parent.view.addSubview(view)
        didMove(toParentViewController: parent)
    }

    func remove() {
        guard parent != nil else { return }

        willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        removeFromParentViewController()
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

The only piece missing is setting the child view controller's view's `frame` after adding it to the parent controller. Add such a line after the call to `add` or add a frame as a second parameter to `add`.

Comment: I am somehow confused on how this will work...I am sending as a parameter the container view ? Or the view controller that I need to add ? Because it looks like I need to send the container view.

Comment: You call `add` and `remove` on the child (contained) view controller. In the case of `add`, you pass the parent (containing) view controller. `remove` is the same as you had it but fixed to properly remove the child view.

Comment: Thanks, it;s working now. I got a little confused by all this child and parents.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to consider it from the child not the parent

```
func remove() {
   willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
   view.removeFromSuperview()
   removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

//

```
child.remove()
```

Comment: leave the add as it it in your question and make the add from the parent , and replace the remove with this answer and make it from the child